# update statement error

Tags: php, mysql

I get a  Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter to be resource, boolean give in c:\program files\EasyPHP......line 71.

when i check the database the row is updated, but i still get this error message

line 71 is if ($duplicates < 0);

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE courses 
  SET   
  course_code = '".$course_code."', 
  course_title = '".$course_title."' ,  
  course_unit = '".$course_unit."'   
  WHERE
  course_code = '".$course_code."'") 
  or die(mysql_error()); 

 $duplicates = mysql_affected_rows($query);
            if ($duplicates > 0)  


 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
 echo"<idv id=\"msg\">" ;                             echo "You have a updated one Course " ;

  echo"</div>" ;
  echo"</div>" ;
   exit();
```

Comment: @pekka what could the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike many other mySQL functions, [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://br.php.net/mysql_affected_rows) doesn't take a query resource as the first parameter: It returns the number of affected rows in the last operation, no matter when that happened.

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier ] )
```

What you can pass to it optionally is the *database connection* resource. But that's necessary only when you deal with more than one of them.

Comment: Correctamundo! I usually just omit that param altogether as it is misleading to others.

Comment: I have tried to use mysql_affected_rows() but i still get the same error.

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi that would surprise me. Are you sure it says "... boolean given" when you give it no parameter? Can you try again?

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi  You are using `$duplicates = mysql_affected_rows();` and it's still saying `Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter to be resource, boolean given`? But that can't be. You aren't giving a boolean, so it can't be complaining about it. Are you really sure?

Comment: It's not showing now, but i'm i not meant to supply the resource i.e $query into mysql_affected_rows() ?

Comment: @dotun no. `mysql_affected_rows()` doesn't need it. It always gives you the result of the last UPDATE operation that took place

Comment: @Pekka I did echo "$duplicate" ; and i got 0. Meanwhile one row was affected is 1.

Comment: @dotun note that if you run this twice, the result will be 1 the first time, and 0 the second time (because the update already happened and there was nothing to do). Could that be the reason why you are getting 0?

Comment: @pekka .. Thanks a "pekkallion" times that was the reason. I did a fresh UPDATE and i got 1. Perfect!